# Insert record with a max of a sub query?

Tags: mysql

I have an insert statement and I want to add a value to it that increments another record for every insert. I got a column called `revision` and I want to add 1 to it for each new row. So...

```
Row 1 = revision = 1
Row 2 = revision = 2
```

But only if the ID matches so it would be something like

`SELECT MAX(revision)+1 FROM versions WHERE id=13`

Which would get `6` for example

Then I want to add that to my insert statement

```
INSERT INTO
versions
    (id, date_added, revision)
VALUES
    (13, NOW(), STUFF FROM OTHER QUERY)
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to do a subquery inside an insert. If I do one it complains that the tables are the same.

Comment: I'm kind of lost.. Have you tried using a `INSERT ... SELECT ... JOIN ... `?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this maybe

```
INSERT INTO
versions
    (date_added, revision)

    (SELECT NOW(),MAX(revision)+1 FROM versions WHERE id=13)
```

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT 13, NOW(),MAX(revision)+1 FROM versions WHERE id=13' at line 1`

Comment: i just removed id. try it now

Comment: Works if I removed the `VALUES ( )` part.